# Marketing Cloud Sent Wrong Email?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We created and updated content in the content builder for an mass email send. The content in the content builder is accurate and has the correct email to send, however the scheduled email blast sent out a previous version with a typo. I know that Journey's need to be updated with the correct version, but because this was scheduled send my understanding is that marketing cloud will always pull the most up to date version.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may have caused our scheduled send to use a previous version?

Answer (score 1):

Once a Send is scheduled, the email version you had associated with the send at that time is the email version that will be sent.  Which means that unfortunately, if you need to edit the email after it was scheduled out already, you will need to cancel that job and recreate it.

Basically what SFMC does is to take a 'snapshot' of the email html at the time the job is created (scheduled) and store it in their queue to help prevent potential errors as well as increase sending speed.

Now, if the issue were with the sending DE or list, that is a different story as this is not processed until send time - meaning you are able to edit this up to the second of send without canceling or recreating.

Comment: Hi Gortonington,

Comment: Hello there Cameron,